# Javascript Immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) and function scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

*Please feel free to update the tittle to a more appropriate one. I was not sure how to word it.*

---

So I have developed a habit (not sure if it is good or bad) of doing the following when I need to write `jQuery` for a site. I only use this on quick and dirty jobs where a single file is needed with few dependencies and AMD, RequireJS, and CommonJS are overkill. It is based off of [this](http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/) article by Greg Franko.

It keeps everything safe and non-conflicting and it does help with readability. Unfortunately though once I found it it became my go to template for all things `jQuery`, and I have never bothered to look into the performance impact of pitfalls of it.

That being said I would like to get some feedback on any issues that may arise with this technique, and specifically if I *should* use it or another technique.

When passed through `JSLint` I always get the following errors:

```
'a' was used before it was defined.
         $('#a').on('click', a);

Unused 'a'.
    function a() {
```

I know why the errors are there and what they mean, but I would like to have a passing JS file with my configuration options, and it works...

```
/*jslint browser: false, couch: false, devel: false, node: false, rhino: false, passfail: false, ass: false, bitwise: false, closure: false, continue: false, debug: false, eqeq: false, evil: false, forin: false, newcap: false, nomen: false, plusplus: false, regexp: false, unparam: false, sloppy: false, stupid: false, sub: false, todo: false, vars: false, white: false, indent: 4 */
/*global window, document, location, jQuery*/

(function (appLoad) {
    "use strict";
    appLoad(window.jQuery, window, document);
}(function ($, window, document) {
    "use strict";

    $(function () {

        // These are executed when the document is ready

        $('#a').on('click', a);
        $('#b').on('click', b);
        $('#c').on('click', c);

    });

    // Logic that is not dependent on the document being ready is below here.
    // I typically place all my logic functions here for readability.

    function a() {
      ...
    }

    function b() {
      ...
    }

    function c() {
      ...
    }
}));
```

Is there a better way of doing what I have illustrated?

Comment: The function declarations at the bottom of your script are actually hoisted to the top of the script. Google function hoisting in JavaScript for a more detailed explanation.   For scoping I'm a huge fan of anonymous closures. See here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin Thank you very much for the link. That article has some great information and I have always wondered if the "Cross-File Private State" was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLint is only complaining that your code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#a').on('click', a);
});

function a() {
    // ...
}
```

Rather than:

```
function a() {
    // ...
}

$(function() {
    $('#a').on('click', a);
});
```

So if you want to get rid of that warning, you could just move those functions around.

That said, at the possible expense of clarity, you could rewrite

```
(function (appLoad) {
    "use strict";
    appLoad(window.jQuery, window, document);
}(function ($, window, document) {
    // ...
}));
```

as

```
(function ($, window, document) {
    // ...
}(window.jQuery, window, document));
```

But that’s not what JSLint is complaining about.

Comment: thanks for the advice I wanted to keep it as close as possible to what I already have so I just moved the 'logical' functions to the top. No more JSLint complainants yah!